# Command binding throws an exception in the UI

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am trying to learn MVVM by making a magic card app.  I don't conceptually know how to link data and commands into the View from the view Model.  I understand how to make data available in the view model but not how to access it from the view.

The main question is what is incorrect in the xaml, I am getting an exception on the button, I assume to do with the binding to the command which also means that the data is probably not working either.

```
<Window x:Class="MagicDB.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MagicDB"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="500">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Name="viewModel" />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="450*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding CardID}" Width="25" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="110"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mana" Binding="{Binding Mana}" Width="30" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Card Text" Binding="{Binding CardTXT}" Width="100*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Flavor Text" Binding="{Binding FlavorTXT}" Width="100*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <!--DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></DataGridCheckBoxColumn-->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Initiliaze Database" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,16,0,0" Name="initdb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
            Command="Binding InitCardDB"/>
</Grid>
```

The main issue is an exception is thrown on the button.  I don't think I am getting the data for the grid either.

```
namespace MagicDB
{
class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private CardDB _cards;
    private Command _InitCardDB;

    public CardDB Cards
    {
        get { return _cards; }
        set { _cards = value; OnPropertyChanged("Cards"); }
    }

   public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //var cards = GetCards();

        //var cardViewModels = new List<CardViewModel>();
        //cards.ForEach(c => cardViewModels.Add(new CardViewModel(c)));
        _InitCardDB = new Command(InitDB, true);
        Cards = new CardDB(); ;
    }

    public Command InitCardDB
    {
        get
        {
            if (_InitCardDB == null)
            {
                _InitCardDB = new Command(
                    param => InitDB()
                );
            }
            return _InitCardDB;
        }

    }

    private void InitDB()
    {
        _cards = new CardDB();
        _cards.InitDB();
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be great, especially what I am doing wrong and where I conceptually made an error.  I might be approaching this incorrectly altogether?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Also the only namespace in my project is "MagicDB", it is used for all my files.

Comment: It sounds like you're still working on figuring out what the `DataContext` is and how bindings work. You may be interested a blog article I wrote recently to explain those concepts in fairly simple terms: [What is this “DataContext” you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataGrid` has no items because you need to set its `ItemsSource`

The Button is causing an exception because you are attempting to assign the string `"Binding InitCardDb"` to the `Command` property instead of using `"{Binding InitCardDb}"`  The `"{}"` tells the XAML processor to use what's called a Markup Extension instead of using the text

Other than that your approach looks correct

Comment: Thanks, where should I set ItemsSource? "<DataGrid ItemsSource="?

Comment: Yes, ItemsSource= "{Binding Path=Cards}"

Comment: I tried both ways and am still not getting the data to display.  Whats interesting is when I do ItemsSource="Cards" the grid shows up in the designer and when I it with ItemsSource={Binding Cards} it doesn't and it also doesn't work. But the button now works!

Comment: How does it know to bind CardID to Cards[i].CardID?

Comment: That's the magic of an ItemsControl. It takes each item in the ItemsSource and displays it somehow. A DataGrid turns each item into a  DataGridRow, a ListBox turns each item into a ListBoxItem, and a ComboBox turns each item into a ComboBoxItem